# bit operations on unsigned char in c++

Tags: c++

I am using C++ in windows OS.

I have 2 values.value1 and value 2.

I want to write value 1 in first 2 bits, and value 2 in last 6 bits of a unsigned char.

and similarly I want to extract value1 and value2 from unsigned char using bit manipulation.

Please help me how to achieve my requirement.

Comment: C++ code works a lot better than a bunch of words that won't compile. Can you explain in terms of code?

Comment: Do you know how to generate and use [bitmasks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing))? If not, that's where you start.

Comment: To put value use something like  `x = (value1<<6)|(value2&0x3f)` and to extract values use  `value1 = (x>>6)&0x3f; value2 =(x&0x3)`

Comment: @TruthSeeker - you should make that an answer. It would be your reputation into the 4 digit range. :)   You are sitting at 999 rep.

Comment: @TruthSeeker  I tried ur solution.when extracting value2 from x, value2 is not receiving correct value.

Comment: @userrmgs: my mistake, please find the update in the answer

Answer (score 2):

Please Try to use bit wise operators something like this,

```
char x = (value1<<6)|(value2&0x3f);
```

and to extract value,

```
value1 = (x>>6) & 0x3;
value2 = (x & 0x3f)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
union my_char {
    unsigned char value;
    struct {
        unsigned char field1 :2;
        unsigned char field2 :6;
    };
};

my_char c;
c.value = 255;
unsigned char c1 = c.field1;
unsigned char c2 = c.field2;
```

Edit:

Jarod42 is right. According to the c++ standard the result is undefined behaviour. Although all (?) compilers will do, what you intended (but thats not a solution).

That's why the c++20 standard has now a bit_cast (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast).

It is easy to implement by yourself, if you are not using c++20.

Comment: union for type punning is not valid (it is UB) in C++.